# Jquery hide/show multiple divs using the same button

Tags: jquery

I am doing some sort of dynamic quiz using jquery. I am currently stuck at hiding/showing the divs using the same button. So, for example, I have this in html:

```
<div id="div1" class="question">
<div id="div2" class="question">
<div id="div3" class="question">
<div id="div4" class="question">
<div id="div5" class="question">

<button type="button" onclick="GetSelectedItem()" id="next">Next</button>
```

This is the jquery part:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

$('#div2, #div3, #div4, #div5').hide();
$('#next').click(function(){
     //code
});
});
```

Using the '#next' button I would like to go through every div, so when I press it it will hide the previous div and show the next one and so on. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this (assuming all your questions have a class of `question` and nothing else does):

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    var curr = $(".question:visible");
    curr.next(".question").show();
    curr.hide();
});
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2eQTa/2/)

Note you can check the value returned by `next()` to handle the end of your quiz.

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2eQTa/1/) that disables the next button when you get to the last question.

Comment: Is amazing how much ways we can solve a problem using jQuery \o/

Answer (score 2):

First off you had errors in your HTML, you weren't closing the divs

This should start you out:

http://jsfiddle.net/crZ69/

HTML

```
<div id="div1" class="question">q1</div>
<div id="div2" class="question">q2</div>
<div id="div3" class="question">q3</div>
<div id="div4" class="question">q4</div>
<div id="div5" class="question">q5</div>

<button type="button" onclick="GetSelectedItem()" id="next">Next</button>
```

JQUERY

```
var qCount = 1;

$('.question').hide();

$('#next').click(function(){
    $('.question').hide();
    $('#div' + qCount).show() ;   
    qCount = qCount + 1;

    if(qCount == 6){ qCount = 1;}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an index to keep track of the open div and increment it when you click the button, hiding all the divs and then only showing the "next" one.

```
$('#div2, #div3, #div4, #div5').hide();
var idx = 0;
$('#next').click(function () {
    idx++;
    if (idx < $('.question').length) $('.question').hide();
    $('.question').eq(idx).show();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qXSwg/)**

Answer (score 1):

This uses a `current` CSS class to keep track of the current question for visibility purposes and tidies up the HTML a bit to use unobtrustive Javascript - http://jsfiddle.net/ZqTsv/

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" class="question current">Question 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="question">Question 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="question">Question 3</div>
<div id="div4" class="question">Question 4</div>
<div id="div5" class="question">Question 5</div>

<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
```

CSS:

```
.question {
    display: none;
}

.question.current {
    display: block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#next").click(function () {
    if ($(".current").next(".question").length) {
       $(".current").removeClass("current").next(".question").addClass("current");     
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it's amazing how many different solutions different people come up with. here is mine:

First fix your html, so the divs have content.

This is the javascript I propose:

```
var idx = 0;
$(document).ready(function (){
    var qs = $('.question');
    qs.hide();
    qs.first().show();
    $('#next').click(function(){
       idx++;
       if( idx >= qs.length ) idx = 0;
       qs.hide();
       qs.eq(idx).show();
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zy3Ty/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[I did something](http://jsbin.com/aruwuh/3)

I think it will be usefull to you =)